# Checkboxes to behave as a radionbutton in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have two checkbox aligned horizontally.
I want if one checkbox is checked the another should go unchecked.

```
switch1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {


        });

switch2.addEventListener('change', function(e) {


        });
```

what is to be written in above events?
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of  element you are using for checkbox. ? like view, button or switch ?. if it is switch then why ?.You should use a custom checkbox (e.g view with image).

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using Switch case like:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.chkBx1:
        if (chk1.isChecked()) {
            chk2.setEnabled(false);

        } else {
            chk1.setEnabled(true);
            chk2.setEnabled(true);

        }
        break;

    case R.id.chkBx2:
        if (chk2.isChecked()) {
            chk1.setEnabled(false);

        } else {
            chk1.setEnabled(true);
            chk2.setEnabled(true);

        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the other `isEnabled` [property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Switch) as enabled/disabled in the onCLick function of every checkBox.

```
switch1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    //Do your business
    switch2.setValue(!switch1.getValue());
    });

switch2.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    //Do your business
    switch1.setValue(!switch2.getValue());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve radio button functionality. Hope this will help you.

```
switch1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    switch1.isSelected = true;
    switch2.isSelected = false;
    switch1.image = 'selected.png';
    switch2.image = 'unselected.png';
});

switch2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    switch2.isSelected = true;
    switch1.isSelected = false;
    switch2.image = 'selected.png';
    switch1.image = 'unselected.png';
});
```